# How to setup ipfs on node or in anular app using aws ec2 instance kubo setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, ipfs, ipfs-kubo

I setup ipfs on AWS-ec2 using kubo v25, now I used ipfs-mini on nodejs to access the AWS ec2 and I added the our AWS ec2 public API and also opened the security groups 5001 and 8080, it didn'work shows connection refused? on aws Daemon is up and running

```
import IPFS from "ipfs-mini";

const ipfs = new IPFS({ host: 'aws-public-ip', port: 5001, protocol: 'http'})

ipfs.add("fileBuffer", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error uploading file to IPFS:', err);
    } else {
      const cid = result;
      console.log('File uploaded to IPFS with CID:', cid);
      // You can use this CID to retrieve the file or share it with others
    }
  });
```

error:
Error uploading file to IPFS: Error: [ipfs-mini] status 0: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED aws-public-ip:5001